# How to extract stringified JSON data using lodash mapValues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, hash, lodash

In React.js app, I am getting a data in stringified JSON format as mentioned below. I need to use `lodash` `mapValues` to extract the data and display it in a required format(eg: table rows)

Data is,

```
{
  "name": "[{\"name\":\"testD\",\"symbol\":\"TESTD\",\"status\":\"Pending\"},{\"name\":\"SSS\",\"symbol\":\"AAA\",\"status\":\"Failed\"}]",
  "symbol": "TESTD",
  "status": "Pending"
}
```

`lodash` function is,

```
mapValues(dynamicStrings, (_, key) => `{{ ${key} }}`)
```

Using this same method, how can I extract and display the data? Please help.

Comment: the values for name will have to be json parsed

Comment: if you have a desired output easier to check

Comment: Yes, for `name` field I want..

Comment: Data itself is kind of Input. If I try to extract using some methods then will get an error.

Comment: maybe run the mapvalues for JSON.parse(obj.name)

Comment: do you have a desired output which you can add to the question

Comment: Not exactly, I just want to display the data in `<table>` format.